# How to interop with C++ dlls when I already have Interface and Type definitions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, interop, c++-cli

I would like to use a set of unmanaged C++ libraries for a large project in my C# .net application. After downloading the code for the libraries, I noticed that the demo project that uses the libraries was actually done in C++/CLI.

Since the demo project was done in C++/CLI the author wen't ahead and added most of the type definitions and interface definitions in header files in the external dependencies folder of this demo application.

If I can, how exactly can I use these definitions to interop with these managed C++ dlls?

To recap:

1. Libraries are written in **unmanaged** C++
2. Demo project is written in **managed** C++ has type definitions and interface definitions created to use the unamanged C++ dlls, they are located in the "External Dependencies" folder and are header files(.h).
3. I want to use these unmanaged C++ dlls in my C# project, can I somehow use the definitions to interop with them?

   4.If not, what would be my best option to interop with them? COM interop?

Comment: Just include the managed C++ code as a reference in your C# code

Comment: The demo application(managed C++ code) is a windows forms application that just demonstrates basic functionality. I am not sure I wan't to include that in my project.

Comment: Oh.  It would be good to have a C++/CLI class library project that calls the functions you need from the unmanaged library, and provides methods of `ref class` types that C# can reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this....

This is an example from the FMod DLL wrapper for c#

```
[DllImport (VERSION.dll)]
private static extern RESULT FMOD_DSPConnection_GetInput        (IntPtr dspconnection, ref IntPtr input);
```

I know it is a lot of work but way better than rewriting the unmanaged DLL.

Not knowing which library you intend to use I can only hope this helps

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for you http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx